# Grid auto hiding in xaml Xamarin Forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am getting a strange error /bug. I have 2 buttons (Save and Clear) inside the grid and when user do not enter any data to fields then it shows the errors printed in labels which are in bottom of each controls.
I have used the scroll view and if design goes to the scrolling then my buttons inside the grid hides automatically. But when I select any picker or focus in any Entry then the Grid (Save and Clear) visible in Page.
I have not written any code in the picker selected Index change.
I am sharing me code. and attaching the screenShot of Page Thanks in advance.

```
<ContentPage.Content>

    <ScrollView x:Name="MyScroll">

        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Padding="10">

        <StackLayout>

            <Entry Text="{Binding BindProductInvModel.ProductInvID}" Margin="0" FontSize="1" IsVisible="false" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" />

            <Label Text="Product Name" Margin="2,-2" FontAttributes="Bold" />
            <Picker x:Name="ProductName" Margin="2,-10,2,5" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                    ItemsSource="{Binding BindProductList}" 
                    ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding ProductName}" 
                    SelectedItem="{Binding BindSelectedProduct,Mode=TwoWay}" 
                    Title="{Binding BindCommonDisplayName.PickerTitleDisplayName}"/>
            <Label x:Name="ProductIDError" Margin="2,-10,2,5" TextColor="Red" IsVisible="false" FontAttributes="Italic" />

            <Label Text="Quanity" Margin="2,-10" FontAttributes="Bold" />

            <Entry x:Name="Quantity"  Text="{Binding BindProductInvModel.Quantity}" Unfocused="Entry_Unfocused" Focused="Entry_Focused"
                       Margin="2,-5,2,5" WidthRequest="150" ReturnType="Next"
                       HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Keyboard="Numeric" />
            <Label x:Name="QuantityError" Margin="2,-10,2,5" 
                   TextColor="Red" IsVisible="false" FontAttributes="Italic" />


            <Label Text="Unit" Margin="2,-10" FontAttributes="Bold" />
            <Entry x:Name="Unit"  Text="{Binding BindProductInvModel.Unit}" IsReadOnly="True"
                       Margin="2,-5,2,5" WidthRequest="150" ReturnType="Next"
                       HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Keyboard="Numeric" />
            <Label x:Name="UnitError" Margin="2,-10,2,5" TextColor="Red" IsVisible="false" FontAttributes="Italic" />

            <Label Text="Vendor Name" Margin="2,-10" FontAttributes="Bold" />
            <Picker x:Name="VendorName" Margin="2,-5,2,5" ItemsSource="{Binding BindVendorList}" 
                    ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding VendorName}" 
                    SelectedItem="{Binding BindSelectedVendor,Mode=TwoWay}" 
                    Title="{Binding BindCommonDisplayName.PickerTitleDisplayName}" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
            <Label x:Name="VendorIDError" Margin="2,-10,2,5" TextColor="Red" IsVisible="false" FontAttributes="Italic" />


            <Label Text="Receiving Date" Margin="2,-12" FontAttributes="Bold" />

            <DatePicker x:Name="PickerRecvDate" Margin="2,-5,2,5" Date="{Binding BindProductInvModel.ReceivingDate,Mode=TwoWay}" 
                        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Format="dd-MM-yyyy"  />
         
            <Label Text="Price" Margin="2,-12" FontAttributes="Bold" />
            <Entry x:Name="Price"  Text="{Binding BindProductInvModel.Price}" Unfocused="Entry_Unfocused" Focused="Entry_Focused"
                       Margin="2,-5,2,5" WidthRequest="150" ReturnType="Next"
                       HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Keyboard="Numeric" />
            <Label x:Name="PriceError" Margin="2,-10,2,5" 
                   TextColor="Red" IsVisible="false" FontAttributes="Italic" />


            <Label Text="Fair" Margin="2,-12" FontAttributes="Bold" />
            <Entry x:Name="Fair"  Text="{Binding BindProductInvModel.Fair}" Unfocused="Entry_Unfocused" Focused="Entry_Focused"
                       Margin="2,-5,2,5" WidthRequest="150" ReturnType="Next"
                       HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Keyboard="Numeric" />
            <Label x:Name="FairError" Margin="2,-10,2,5" 
                   TextColor="Red" IsVisible="false" FontAttributes="Italic" />


            <Label Text="OtherCharges" Margin="2,-12" FontAttributes="Bold" />
            <Entry x:Name="OtherCharges" Text="{Binding BindProductInvModel.OtherCharges}" Unfocused="Entry_Unfocused" Focused="Entry_Focused"
                       Margin="2,-5,2,5" WidthRequest="150" ReturnType="Next"
                       HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Keyboard="Numeric" />
            <Label x:Name="OtherChargesError" Margin="2,-10,2,5" 
                   TextColor="Red" IsVisible="false" FontAttributes="Italic" />


            <Label Text="Total" 
                   Margin="2,-12" FontAttributes="Bold" />
            <Entry Text="{Binding BindProductInvModel.Total}"
                       Margin="2,-5,2,5" WidthRequest="150" ReturnType="Next" IsEnabled="False"
                       HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Keyboard="Numeric" />
            <Label x:Name="TotalError" Margin="2,-10,2,5" 
                   TextColor="Red" IsVisible="false" FontAttributes="Italic" />

      </StackLayout>


            <StackLayout>

                <Grid HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Margin="2,-12">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
             </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Button Text="Save" x:Name="BtnSave" 
                        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" CornerRadius="10" 
                        BorderWidth="2" BackgroundColor="#ff6633" TextColor="#fff" 
                        Margin="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Command="{Binding SaveCommand}" />

            <Button Text="Clear" x:Name="BtnClear" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                        CornerRadius="10" BorderWidth="2" BackgroundColor="#bfbfbf" 
                        TextColor="#fff" Margin="2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Command="{Binding ClearCommand}" />
        </Grid>

            </StackLayout>


        </StackLayout>
        
        
    </ScrollView>

</ContentPage.Content>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: When you scroll it to down than also it not shows buttons?

Comment: yes when i scroll down then button hides but when clikc on picker they become visible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make the grid with buttons always visable when you scroll or select any picker, you could make the buttons outside the scrollview.

```
 <StackLayout> 
 <ScrollView x:Name="MyScroll">

    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Padding="10">

    <StackLayout>

        <Entry Text="{Binding BindProductInvModel.ProductInvID}" Margin="0" FontSize="1" IsVisible="false" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" />

        <Label Text="Product Name" Margin="2,-2" FontAttributes="Bold" />
        <Picker x:Name="ProductName" Margin="2,-10,2,5" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                ItemsSource="{Binding BindProductList}" 
                ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding ProductName}" 
                SelectedItem="{Binding BindSelectedProduct,Mode=TwoWay}" 
                Title="{Binding BindCommonDisplayName.PickerTitleDisplayName}"/>
        <Label x:Name="ProductIDError" Margin="2,-10,2,5" TextColor="Red" IsVisible="false" FontAttributes="Italic" />

        <Label Text="Quanity" Margin="2,-10" FontAttributes="Bold" />

        <Entry x:Name="Quantity"  Text="{Binding BindProductInvModel.Quantity}" Unfocused="Entry_Unfocused" Focused="Entry_Focused"
                   Margin="2,-5,2,5" WidthRequest="150" ReturnType="Next"
                   HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Keyboard="Numeric" />
        <Label x:Name="QuantityError" Margin="2,-10,2,5" 
               TextColor="Red" IsVisible="false" FontAttributes="Italic" />


        <Label Text="Unit" Margin="2,-10" FontAttributes="Bold" />
        <Entry x:Name="Unit"  Text="{Binding BindProductInvModel.Unit}" IsReadOnly="True"
                   Margin="2,-5,2,5" WidthRequest="150" ReturnType="Next"
                   HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Keyboard="Numeric" />
        <Label x:Name="UnitError" Margin="2,-10,2,5" TextColor="Red" IsVisible="false" FontAttributes="Italic" />

        <Label Text="Vendor Name" Margin="2,-10" FontAttributes="Bold" />
        <Picker x:Name="VendorName" Margin="2,-5,2,5" ItemsSource="{Binding BindVendorList}" 
                ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding VendorName}" 
                SelectedItem="{Binding BindSelectedVendor,Mode=TwoWay}" 
                Title="{Binding BindCommonDisplayName.PickerTitleDisplayName}" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
        <Label x:Name="VendorIDError" Margin="2,-10,2,5" TextColor="Red" IsVisible="false" FontAttributes="Italic" />


        <Label Text="Receiving Date" Margin="2,-12" FontAttributes="Bold" />

        <DatePicker x:Name="PickerRecvDate" Margin="2,-5,2,5" Date="{Binding BindProductInvModel.ReceivingDate,Mode=TwoWay}" 
                    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Format="dd-MM-yyyy"  />
     
        <Label Text="Price" Margin="2,-12" FontAttributes="Bold" />
        <Entry x:Name="Price"  Text="{Binding BindProductInvModel.Price}" Unfocused="Entry_Unfocused" Focused="Entry_Focused"
                   Margin="2,-5,2,5" WidthRequest="150" ReturnType="Next"
                   HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Keyboard="Numeric" />
        <Label x:Name="PriceError" Margin="2,-10,2,5" 
               TextColor="Red" IsVisible="false" FontAttributes="Italic" />


        <Label Text="Fair" Margin="2,-12" FontAttributes="Bold" />
        <Entry x:Name="Fair"  Text="{Binding BindProductInvModel.Fair}" Unfocused="Entry_Unfocused" Focused="Entry_Focused"
                   Margin="2,-5,2,5" WidthRequest="150" ReturnType="Next"
                   HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Keyboard="Numeric" />
        <Label x:Name="FairError" Margin="2,-10,2,5" 
               TextColor="Red" IsVisible="false" FontAttributes="Italic" />


        <Label Text="OtherCharges" Margin="2,-12" FontAttributes="Bold" />
        <Entry x:Name="OtherCharges" Text="{Binding BindProductInvModel.OtherCharges}" Unfocused="Entry_Unfocused" Focused="Entry_Focused"
                   Margin="2,-5,2,5" WidthRequest="150" ReturnType="Next"
                   HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Keyboard="Numeric" />
        <Label x:Name="OtherChargesError" Margin="2,-10,2,5" 
               TextColor="Red" IsVisible="false" FontAttributes="Italic" />


        <Label Text="Total" 
               Margin="2,-12" FontAttributes="Bold" />
        <Entry Text="{Binding BindProductInvModel.Total}"
                   Margin="2,-5,2,5" WidthRequest="150" ReturnType="Next" IsEnabled="False"
                   HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Keyboard="Numeric" />
        <Label x:Name="TotalError" Margin="2,-10,2,5" 
               TextColor="Red" IsVisible="false" FontAttributes="Italic" />

  </StackLayout>
   
    </StackLayout>
    
    
</ScrollView>
  <StackLayout>

            <Grid HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Margin="2,-12">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
         </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Button Text="Save" x:Name="BtnSave" 
                    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" CornerRadius="10" 
                    BorderWidth="2" BackgroundColor="#ff6633" TextColor="#fff" 
                    Margin="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Command="{Binding SaveCommand}" />

        <Button Text="Clear" x:Name="BtnClear" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                    CornerRadius="10" BorderWidth="2" BackgroundColor="#bfbfbf" 
                    TextColor="#fff" Margin="2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Command="{Binding ClearCommand}" />
    </Grid>

        </StackLayout>

</StackLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for the code  and i have move the button grid oustide of scroll view but if i rotate the device then buttons are half visible and half invisible. I have shared the screenshot on below link https://www.linkpicture.com/view.php?img=LPic60efefd3d8ad21490122652

Comment: Change the ` Margin="2,-12"`.  Use a positive number like 1,2,3 instead of negative number -12.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir for your kindly support

Answer (score 0):

It was a bug workaround:

Wrapping the ScrollView in a ContentView seems to be a good workaround.

```
<ContentPage.Content>
        <ContentView>
             <ScrollView VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                <StackLayout>
                <!-- Content -->
                </StackLayout>
            </ScrollView>
        </ContentView>
   </ContentPage.Content>
```

https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/13597